# WPF add Margin Binding using 'Validation.HasError' as Path at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML code that represents a TextBox with validation, when an error occurs then the margin is increased so that the message is not overlapping other UI elements under this TextBox.

In XAML every part of this works like I intended for it to work.
Validation is implemented using the `IDataErrorInfo` interface

```
<TextBox 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}"         
    Style="{StaticResource baseMargins}"
    Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.HasError), Converter={StaticResource MarginConv}}" 
    Padding="{StaticResource basePadding}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding 
            Path="Email" 
            Mode="TwoWay" 
            UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
            ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Now I want the create the same but at runtime. The page has an `ItemsControl` that I fill with the generated `TextBoxes`.

The following code shows how I create this `TextBox`

```
private static void CreateForStackOverflow()
{
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

    Binding textBinding = new Binding();
    textBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Email");
    textBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    textBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    textBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
    textBinding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;

    textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textBinding);

    var valTemplate = (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.FindResource("validationErrorTemplate");
    Validation.SetErrorTemplate(textBox, valTemplate);

    Binding valBinding = new Binding();
    valBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
    valBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Validation.HasError");
    valBinding.Converter = new Converters.BoolMarginConverter();

    textBox.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, valBinding);
}
```

Now the validation works, errors are created but the only thing that does not work is the Binding for the `MarginProperty`. This is never triggered.

The following error is displayed in the Output window:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'Validation' property not found on 'object' ''TextBox' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Validation.HasError; 
DataItem='TextBox' (Name=''); 
target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); 
target property is 'Margin' (type 'Thickness')
```

I have found it could maybe have something to do with my `DataContext] but it is set in the XAML, and setting that Context was the solution for all those people but not for me.

Using Snoop (2.10.0.0) I can see that the `TextBox` has a `Validation` property.

[image: Snoop Validation Property]

Here is what Snoop shows on the `Margin`property.

[image: Snoop Margin Property]

This a what the overlapping errors look like.
[image: Overlapping errors]

And the code for the BoolMarginConverter is the following:

```
public class BoolMarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool hasError = (bool)value;
        return hasError ? new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 20) : new Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But this is never executed because the `Validation.HasError` could not be found.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: The error template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel 
            Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.
            Dock="Bottom" 
            ClipToBounds="True">
            <Grid
                Width="12" 
                Height="12">
                <Ellipse 
                    Width="12" 
                    Height="12" 
                    Fill="Red" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"    
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock 
                    Foreground="White" 
                    FontWeight="Heavy" 
                    FontSize="8" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"     
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    TextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="X"
                    ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"  />
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock 
                Foreground="Red" 
                FontWeight="Bold" 
                TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                Margin="2,0,0,0"
                Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors),           Converter=converters:ValidationErrorsToStringConverter}}" 
                />
        </StackPanel>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner"/>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Without repro'ing it locally - the only thing I would suggest is to bake the margin directly into a control template and have seperate control template's for error and non error'd states. This also might have something to do with "Freezing" but I don't have enough experience to comment on that. Good luck.

Comment: @d347hm4n The template (see edit in question) is overlapping the content so adding a margin would not do anything (I thank), I will test it out but I don't think this will work

Comment: Adding a margin in a style works ok for me.  Why isn't all that stuff just in a resource dictionary as a style? You could then just set the style in code.

Comment: I agree with @Andy i don't see why you need so much code behind for what you want  to achieve

Comment: @Andy I will look into this but it is not an answer to why the binding is never triggered when a validation error occurs. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the brackets on `(Validation.HasError)` ...

`Validation.HasError` ==> `(Validation.HasError)`

```
valBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("(Validation.HasError)");
```

Maybe someday this will help someone.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use code to do all that and even then what you have seems over complicated.
The below markup works for me.
I have a public Int property in code behind just to test by typing a character.

Obviously, if you want to apply this by code then put an x:Key on your style and then you can go grab it out resources and apply it. Mine applies to all textboxes. I don't really follow why you wouldn't want that anyhow.

I would also suggest that moving ui around like this is limiting. I'd prefer a border and outline colour change and see all the errors in a tooltip. You can only fit one this way.

```
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <StackPanel 
        Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
        ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Grid
            Width="12" 
            Height="12">
                                <Ellipse 
                Width="12" 
                Height="12" 
                Fill="Red" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"    
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock 
                Foreground="White" 
                FontWeight="Heavy" 
                FontSize="8" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"     
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                TextAlignment="Center"
                Text="X"
                ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"  />
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock 
            Foreground="Red" 
            FontWeight="Bold" 
            TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
            Margin="2,0,0,0"
            Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}" 
            />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,20"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyNum, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Banana"/>
        <Button Content="Some Button"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```